# Transitioning innerRadius of svg.arc - D3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, transition, sunburst-diagram

I have a question, that is closely related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10089453/transitioning-sunburst-in-d3-js).

As opposed to the example, I also  need to transition the innerRadius of the sunburst, hence the innerRadius property of the d3.svg.arc(). I know it has to be done in a similar fashion with respect to the transition of the "d" (with attrTween by storing the old innerRadius) but I didn't managed to do it.

Any suggestion? A code snippet would be great!

Comment: Did you see the [pie-transition example](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/examples/pie/pie-transition.html) in the [D3 Git repository](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/)?

Comment: I quickly looked at it days ago if I'm not wrong.. I'll take a closer look then. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you say "sunburst", do you mean a multi-colored Pie, where all the arcs are different?  If so, the example "[Multiple D3 Pie Charts Mixed In With Common HTML Layout Constructs](http://bl.ocks.org/2212156)" transitions the inner radius while drawing the pie (just search for the word transition in the code).

Another option is to look at this "[Sunburst Coffee Flavor Wheel](http://www.jasondavies.com/coffee-wheel/)" example, which is more complex but shows how to transition multiple arcs, simultaneously.

I hope it helps.

Frank