# How can I handle a pie chart with no non-zero data?

Tags: svg, d3.js

I have built a dashboard that displays many bar and pie charts. It also has the ability to filter. Some filters cause there to be no data for the pie charts, and this causes my app to break.

It has to do with `d3.svg.arc`. The error I get is 'problem parsing d="MNaN, NaN...". I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10090745/1406664) by Mike Bostock, and I think it's related.

Should I

1. Figure out how to handle the case where the data is 0, or
2. Use .exit? (My attempts here have given me problems on the initial draw, which sometimes also won't have data).