# D3 - Transition Arcs in Sunburst Chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, charts

I have a sunburst chart made in D3. Each 'petal' represents a subset of data. When a user clicks on one of the 'petals', I would like it to transition, fanning out to only show that subset (see image):

[image]

I'm having trouble getting the code to properly transition.

On click, all 'petals' (besides the selected one) should disappear and the remain paths should animate along the circle (using attrTween, arcTween, and interpolate?). The primary value that would be changing is the angleSize (`var angleSize = (2 * Math.PI) / theData.length;`).

I've tried using [this](http://bl.ocks.org/j0hnsmith/5591116), [this](https://bl.ocks.org/kerryrodden/477c1bfb081b783f80ad), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22312943/d3-sunburst-transition-given-updated-data-trying-to-animate-not-snap), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10089453/transitioning-sunburst-in-d3-js) as reference without much success. What's the best way to handle the animation?

Thanks for your time!

--> See [Plunker Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/xIigDbEEWs3vbCvCBuHT?p=preview). <--

Code is below:

```
  var colors = {
    'Rank1' : '#3FA548',
    'Rank2' : '#00B09E',
    'Rank3' : '#8971B3',
    'Rank4' : '#DFC423',
    'Rank5' : '#E74341'
  };

  var $container = $('.chart'),
      m = 40,
      width = $container.width() - m,
      height = $container.height() - m,
      r = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

  var study = null;
  var arc = d3.svg.arc();

  d3.csv('text.csv', ready);

  function ready(err, data) {
    if (err) console.warn('Error', err);

    var svg = d3.select('.chart')
                .append('svg')
                .attr({
                  'width' : (r + m) * 2,
                  'height' : (r + m) * 2,
                  'class' : 'container'
                })
                .append('g')
                .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width / 4) + ', ' + (height / 2) + ' )'); 

    var slice = svg.selectAll('.slice');

    function updateChart(study) {
      if (study) {
        var theData = data.filter(function(d) { 
              return d.study_name === study; 
            });
      } else {
        var theData = data;
      }

      slice = slice.data(theData);

      slice.enter()
           .append('g')
           .attr('class', 'slice'); 

      var angleSize = (2 * Math.PI) / theData.length; 

      var startRadArr = [],
          endRadArr = [];

      for ( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
        var startRadius = (width / 20),
            endRadius = startRadius;

        for ( var x = 0; x < 4; x++ ) {
          startRadArr.push(startRadius);

          if ( x == 0 ) {
            endRadius += Number(data[i].group1_score) * (width / 500);
          } else if ( x == 1 ) {
            endRadius += Number(data[i].group2_score) * (width / 500);
          } else if ( x == 2 ) {
            endRadius += Number(data[i].group3_score) * (width / 500);
          } else {
            endRadius += Number(data[i].group4_score) * (width / 500);
          }

          endRadArr.push(endRadius);
          startRadius = endRadius + 0.3;
        }
      }

      var startRadGroup = [],
          endRadGroup = [];

      for (i = 0; i < startRadArr.length; i += 4) { 
        startRadGroup.push(startRadArr.slice(i, i + 4)); 
      }

      for (i = 0; i < endRadArr.length; i += 4) { 
        endRadGroup.push(endRadArr.slice(i, i + 4)); 
      }

      slice.selectAll('path')
           .remove();

      for ( var x = 0; x < 4; x++ ) {
        slice.append('path')
             .attr({
               'class' : function(d, i) {
                 if ( x == 0 ) {
                   return d.group1_class;
                 } else if ( x == 1 ) {
                   return d.group2_class;
                 } else if ( x == 2 ) {
                   return d.group3_class;
                 } else {
                   return d.group4_class;
                 }
               },
               'company' : function(d, i) { 
                 return d.brand_name; 
               },
               'cat' : function(d, i) {
                  if ( x == 0 ) {
                   return 'Group1';
                 } else if ( x == 1 ) {
                   return 'Group2';
                 } else if ( x == 2 ) {
                   return 'Group3';
                 } else {
                   return 'Group4';
                 }
               },
               'study' : function(d, i) { 
                 return d.study_name; 
               },
               'companyid' : function(d, i) { 
                 return d.brand_id; 
               },
               'startradius' : function(d, i) {
                 return startRadGroup[i][x];
               },
               'endradius' : function(d, i) {
                 return endRadGroup[i][x];
               },
               'startangle' : function(d, i) {
                 return angleSize * i;
               },
               'endangle' : function(d, i) {
                 return angleSize * (i + 1);
               }
             })
             .on('click', selectStudy);
      }

      slice.exit()
           .remove();

      slice.selectAll('path')
           .attr({
             'd' : function(d) {
                return arc({
                  innerRadius : +d3.select(this)[0][0].attributes.startradius.nodeValue,
                  outerRadius : +d3.select(this)[0][0].attributes.endradius.nodeValue,
                  startAngle : +d3.select(this)[0][0].attributes.startangle.nodeValue,
                  endAngle : +d3.select(this)[0][0].attributes.endangle.nodeValue
                })
              }
           });
    }

    function selectStudy(d) {
      study = $(this).attr('study');
      updateChart(study);
    } 

    updateChart();
  }
```

**EDIT**
Updated the code (based on [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5681974)) to include a properly working enter, update, and exit pattern. Still unsure about the transition however. Most of the examples I've linked to use something similar to `d3.interpolate(this._current, a);`, tweening between differing data.

In this chart, this._current and a are the same, angleSize (`var angleSize = (2 * Math.PI) / theData.length;`), startAngle, and endAngle are the only thing that changes.

Comment: There are a few things complicating this - first and foremost, that you are removing all the slices before you attempt to transition them, yet you will need to recreate them with their starting point to begin the transition. Also consider reformatting the data into a deeper structure so you don't need to loop 4 times over each point.

Comment: @Owen Yeah. The remove() was a temp fix for some weird behavior (new data would append over old data). Commented out the remove --> [LINK](https://plnkr.co/edit/JwCy84YBVSxDERZOp1z0?p=preview). As for the data, I unfortunately don't have any control over the format. Will look for a JS solution (any suggestions?). Would prefer not to manually change in Excel.

Comment: Also any reason to use d3 v3 instead of v4?

Comment: @Owen Familiarity. Is there something in v4 that would help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not really binding data to the elements, and therefore the transition is not possible. I mangled your code a little bit so the data contains all the nested information about the starting and ending angles, so that it can be bound to the paths inside each slice.

Take a look at this Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/a7cxRplzy66Pc1arM2a9?p=preview

Here's the listing of the modified version:

```
var colors = {
    Rank1: '#3FA548',
    Rank2: '#00B09E',
    Rank3: '#8971B3',
    Rank4: '#DFC423',
    Rank5: '#E74341'
};

// Configuration
var $container = $('.chart'),
    m = 40,
    width = $container.width() - m,
    height = $container.height() - m,
    r = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var study = null;

var arc = d3.svg.arc();

// Load data
d3.csv('text.csv', ready);

// Data loaded callback
function ready(err, data) {
    if (err) console.warn('Error', err);

    var svg = d3.select('.chart')
        .append('svg')
        .attr({
            'width': (r + m) * 2,
            'height': (r + m) * 2,
            'class': 'container'
        })
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width / 4) + ', ' + (height / 2) + ' )');

    var slices = svg.selectAll('.slice');

    function updateChart(study) {
        var theData = data;

        if (study) {
            theData = data.filter(function (d) {
                return d.study_name === study;
            });
        }

        var angleSize = (2 * Math.PI) / theData.length;

        theData.forEach(function (item, i) {
            var startRadius = (width / 20),
                endRadius = startRadius,
                groupName;

            item.paths = [];

            for (var g = 0; g < 4; g++) {
                item.paths[g] = {};

                item.paths[g].startRadius = startRadius;

                groupName = 'group' + (g + 1) + '_score';

                endRadius += Number(item[groupName]) * (width / 500);

                item.paths[g].endRadius = endRadius;

                startRadius = endRadius + 0.3;
            }
        });

        // Set the data
        slices = slices.data(theData);

        // Enter
        slices.enter()
            .append('g')
            .attr('class', 'slice');

        // Exit
        slices.exit()
            .remove();

        // Update
        slices
            .transition()
            .duration(750)
            .each(function (dSlice, iSlice) {
                var slice = d3.select(this);

                var paths = slice.selectAll('path');

                // Set data
                paths = paths.data(dSlice.paths);

                // Exit
                paths.exit()
                    .remove();

                // Enter
                paths.enter()
                    .append('path')
                    .attr('class', 'path');

                // Update
                paths
                    .transition()
                    .attr({
                        'class': function (d, i) {
                            return dSlice['group' + (i + 1) + '_class'];
                        },
                        'company': dSlice.brand_name,
                        'cat': function (d, i) {
                            return 'Group' + (i + 1);
                        },
                        'study': function (d, i) {
                            return dSlice.study_name;
                        },
                        'companyid': function (d, i) {
                            return dSlice.brand_id;
                        },
                        'startradius': function (d, i) {
                            return d.startRadius;
                        },
                        'endradius': function (d, i) {
                            return d.endRadius;
                        },
                        'startangle': function (d, i) {
                            return angleSize * iSlice;
                        },
                        'endangle': function (d, i) {
                            return angleSize * (iSlice + 1);
                        },
                        'd': function (d) {
                            return arc({
                                innerRadius: +d.startRadius, 
                                outerRadius: +d.endRadius, 
                                startAngle: +angleSize * iSlice, 
                                endAngle: +angleSize * (iSlice + 1) 
                            })
                        }
                    })
                    .duration(750);

                paths.on('click', selectStudy);
            });

        function selectStudy(d, i) {
            study = $(this).attr('study');

            updateChart(study);
        }
    }

    updateChart();
}
```

As you can see, the key is correctly preparing the data (let's say the format in your example `.tsv` file is not the best choice, but sometimes we can't choose our data sources...)

Then afterwards, by putting the code for the paths generation inside the `.each` call on the slices, the data can be accessed from the `function (d, i) { ... }` callbacks and every element happens to receive the corresponding data.

Another trick is using the slices data (accessed inside the `.each` function via the `dSlice` and `iSlice` vars) on the paths' callbacks. This way the paths can consume this data for their own purposes. In this case, the `company` and `study_name` properties.

Now in order to tweak the transition and make it more accurate, the starting attributes can change. You can try by setting up some attributes for the paths in the `.enter()` phase.

Comment: To make the transition stable you should massage the data on initial load and provide a key function so the enter/update/exit functions know which slices belong where. See [this plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/b91oOy2PYRdGclZfwzOp?p=preview) (but note the transition is simply transitioning the path, not the angles).

Comment: Thank you! You guys are life-savers.